# Interpreting escaped unicode chars in C++

Tags: c++, string, unicode

Let's say I have a file called `test.txt` containing this text :

```
\u003cdiv style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\"\u003e\nAppending is not creating
```

If I want to read it `char` by `char`, here is what it looks like :

### Code 1 : reading from file

```
ifstream file;
file.open("test.txt");
string line;
while (getline(file, line)){
    cout << line<< endl; // prints \u003cdiv style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\"\u003e\nAppending is not creating
}
```

However, if I declare the same string inside the code, escaped characters are detected and printed as such.

### Code 2 : simple string

```
string line2 ("\u003cdiv style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\"\u003e\nAppending is 
cout << line2<< endl; // prints <div style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">\n   Appending is not creating
```

This is perfectly normal since `\` is the escape char for C++ strings.

This raises a question : is it possible to get the same result with the first code (ie, to have each line interpreted like the string defined in code 2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STL class `string` doesn't have any function for doing this. You would have to implement your own function to change the escaped characters expressions to its correct escaped character. This function would look like this:

```
string parse_escaped_characters(string s) {
    string s2;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == '\\') {
            switch (s[i+1]) {
                case 'n': s2 += '\n'; ++i; break;
                case '\"': s2 += '\"'; ++i; break;
                //and so on...
            }
        }
        else s2 += s[i];
    }
    return s2;
 }
```

Or you could search for a library to treat strings which includes this functionality.

Comment: this fails (UB) if the last character is `'\\'` as you access `s[i+1]`.

Comment: @bolov Well that shouldn’t happen according to the specifications. Of course it would be nicer to guard against it instead of failing silently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph according to the standard, until c++11 it is undefined behaviour: `operator[pos]` with `pos == size()` for a `non-const string object`.

Comment: @bolov That’s not my point. My point is that the last character **cannot** be `'\'` because that would be an invalid escape sequence. It needs to be followed by at least one more character. The code has another bug, though: it doesn’t increment `i` when an escape sequence is parsed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Oh ok I see. However, I think the function should work whether the input is valid or not (in the sense of correct escape characters).